# Est-ce que « c’est le plus beau moins cher » et « c’est le plus beau des moins chers » sont des tournures équivalentes?

Tags: choix-de-mot, formulation-idiomatique, formulation, reformulation

> Ce bureau-ci, c’est le plus beau moins cher.

> Ce bureau-ci, c’est le plus beau des moins chers.

EDIT*

J’ajoute aussi la phrase ci-après:

> Ce bureau-ci, c’est le plus beau parmi/dans les moins chers.

EDIT**

D’autres énonciations qui me viennent en tête:

> Ce bureau-ci, c’est le plus beau à bon marché.

> Ce bureau-ci, c’est le plus beau parmi ceux à bon marché.

Laquelle serait préférable?
Auriez-vous pensé l’idée différemment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En français métropolitain ces deux tournures ne sont pas équivalentes et la première (comprise elliptiquement) est à la limite de l'acceptabilité. On doit vraiment dire « C'est plus beau lorsque c'est moins cher. ».

- Ce bureau-ci, c’est le plus beau des moins chers. (*acceptable*)
- Ce bureau-ci, c’est le plus beau à bon marché. (*difficilement acceptable*)
- Ce bureau-ci, c’est le plus beau parmi ceux à bon marché. (*acceptable*)

La dernière formulation est la meilleure en cela que l'idée voulue s'impose immédiatemment et fortement à l'esprit.

Il y a d'autres  façons d'exprimer cela. Suivent quelques possibilités.

- Parmi les bureaux bon marché celui-ci est le plus beau.
- Dans le bon marché ce bureau-ci est le plus beau.
- Dans le bon marché c'est ce bureau-ci qui est le plus beau.
- Il n'y a pas de bureau bon marché plus beau que celui-ci.
- De tous les bureaux bon marché celui-ci est le plus beau.

Comment: Je vous remercie LPH pour votre réponse. Concernant la troisième possibilité que vous m’avez proposée, pourrait-on plutôt écrire « Dans le bon marché c’est ce bureau-ci le plus beau » (sans « qui est ») sans compromettre le degré d’acceptabilité de la phrase?

Comment: dans le bon marché?? Oui, mais très colloquialement.

Comment: @Jean-LouFrenette *Dans le bon marché* n'est pas du tout idiomatique, je n'ai jamais entendu cette expression. La seule compréhension que j'aurais si quelqu'un me disait ça serait un variante maladroite de *Au Bon Marché*, (le [Bon Marché](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Bon_March%C3%A9) est un grand magasin parisien). Une forme acceptable serait *Dans **les** bon marché, c'est ce bureau le plus beau*.

Comment: @Lambie Attention, *colloquial* ou son dérivé *colloquialement* n'existent pas en français.

Comment: @jlliagre J’imagine que LPH a proposé une expression qui prend modèle sur la tournure « dans les bas prix ».

Comment: Tu as bien écrit *dans **les**  bas prix* et c'est tout à fait acceptable, mais LPH a écrit l'équivalent de *dans **le** bas prix* qui n'existe pas.

Comment: Whoops, pour colloquial. Registre familier. LPH a écrit: "dans le bon marché" aussi. Jean-Lou: Nous indiquer le niveau de langue que vous recherchez.

Comment: @Lambie Oui, LPH a écrit *dans le bon marché* mais cette expression n'existe pas. Il n'existe donc aucun registre où on puisse la classer, ou peut-être le registre des hapax...

Comment: @Jean-LouFrenette Je le crois,oui, on peut se passer de  qui est ».

Comment: @Lambie [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/march%C3%A9) : **(Le) bon marché** b) Ensemble des produits vendus à petit prix par un marchand. Toute sa colère de maniaque s'exhalait contre les misérables qui déshonoraient son métier, en vendant du bon marché, de la camelote, des articles dont les chiens (...) n'auraient pas voulu se servir (Zola, Bonheur dames,1883, p. 567). (Dans le bon marché, parmi le bon marché, en dehors du bon marché).

Comment: @LPH Ton commentaire peut laisser croire que l'on trouve dans le TLFi les formes *dans le bon marché, parmi le bon marché, en dehors du bon marché*, ce qui n'est pas le cas. Je ne dis pas que la forme *dans le bon marché* est inconcevable ou non grammaticale mais simplement qu'elle est trop improbable avec ce sens aujourd'hui. Elle est d'ailleurs aussi ambiguë que son opposée *dans le cher* que tous le monde ici comprendrait comme signifiant *dans le Cher*.

Comment: @jlliagre Je sais que "dans le bon marché" n'existe pas; c'est bien pour cela que je l'ai signalé.

Comment: Je trouve _dans le bon marché_ bizarre mais ça ressemble à un calque de _dans l'usager_. Je (Qc.) reconnais _dans l'usager_ (ce qui est de seconde main, le domaine de, l'ensemble des choses de seconde main) mais quand on essaye ce tour-là (poss. figé) avec _bon marché_ on a plein d'ambiguités et la phrase devient en trompe-l'oeil ; les noms des commerce, même au Québec on avait [_au bon marché](https://youtu.be/huzOHxjMDxk) (oui papa)_, puis on a le marché qui serait le bon (au bon endroit) etc. Je trouve le tour de Zola meilleur car sans préposition, dans une liste qui le soutient.

Comment: @Lambie La suite de ton commentaire laissait penser le contraire Tu as écrit ***oui**, mais trés xxx*, ce qui signifie que c'est acceptable dans le registre xxx.

Comment: @NoëlloMiqueron *Dans l'usagé*, par opposition avec *dans le neuf*, je comprends ça mais je dirais plus *dans l'occasion*.

Comment: "Ah tu sais, ce mec-là, il a de l'avenir dans le bon marché, il s'en sort très bien. Il n'aime pas les fringues classe dans sa boutique. Faut voir comment il fait lui."

Comment: @jlliagre Oui oui c'est cet emploi là, probablement que « usagé » c'est un anglicisme courant chez nous. Wow, j'avais écrit _usager_ je vois que ça existe comme adjectif pour _d'usage courant_. Eh, bien, moins niaiseux à chaque commentaire.

Comment: @Lambie Je peux aussi comprendre ta phrase comme si tu disais dans le bon _créneau_ et donc pour moi il y a ambiguité. En fait même d'occasion (_dans l'occasion_) n'y ferait pas ici pour moi (il me faudrait _domaine de_, un truc du genre) dans ta phrase parce que ça sonne bizarre, je le trouve imprécis. Je dirais simplement _dans la vente au détail à bas prix_ ou une affaire de même. C'est qu'on glisse vers d'autres tours et d'autres sens ou l'inusité, d'où les commentaires.

Comment: Il faut peut-être un petit tour dans la Rue du Sentier, à Paris.

Comment: @Lambie Ta phrase est bien, sauf *dans le bon marché*. On ne dit pas non plus *il a de l'avenir dans le cher*. Peut-être : *ce gars la, son avenir, c'est les fringues bon marché*.

Comment: **Renault a-t-il encore un avenir dans le haut de gamme ?**  EUROPE 1//X a encore de l'avenir dans le bon marché? bon marché contre  haut de gamme, p. ex. Autre chose? Franchement, c'est fatiguant.

Comment: @Lambie Ah, *ce gars là*, c'est un commerçant. Alors d'accord, ça passe, je n'avais pas compris mais on s'éloigne quand même de plus en plus de la phrase : *Dans le bon marché ce bureau ci est le plus beau*.

Comment: @jlliagre Lettre ouverte à ''ce mec-là'' que l'on connaît depuis toujours https://www.lerugbynistere.fr/news/lettre-ouverte-a-ce-mec-la-que-lon-connait-depuis-toujours-1408201606.php En s'éloigne mais ça marche pour un registre familier.

Comment: @Lambie Je ne parlais pas de *ce mec-là*, au contraire, j'ai même écrit "ta phrase est bien" mais puisque tu reviens dessus, je pense que tu utilises le mot "mec" comme tu utiliserais *guy* en anglais, alors que "mec" est bien plus familier que *guy* / "gars" et très souvent péjoratif, spécialement dans l'expression "ce mec-là". Le mot *mec* peut aussi être utilisé de manière non péjorative pour insister sur le côté viril d'un homme (*mon mec à moi*, *entre mecs*, etc.) comme dans la page que tu as proposée. Ce qui passe pour un rugbyman ne passe pas forcément pour un commerçant du Sentier.

Comment: @jlliagre J'avais donné la citation pour montrer ce **mec-là**. **Pour montrer le tiret**. Pas pour montrer le sens, que je comprends très bien, merci.

Comment: @Lambie Ah, les coquilles, on en fait tous : *c'est fati**g**ant*, ***On** s'éloigne*, dans la **r**ue du Sentier, ***D**ans le bon marché*.

Comment: How about you go and spend 15-17 years in an English-speaking country and then we talk then? Typos, yes, but not in the actual sentence I posted using "dans le bon marché". Voir la plaque dans la photo: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rue_du_Sentier_(Paris), Ce n'est pas "une faute grave professionnelle".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133209/discussion-between-jlliagre-and-lambie).